# jQuery: How to change icon along side text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have following JsFiddle:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <a id="IdAdvanceSearch" href="javascript:;" 
    class="col-sm-offset-2"
   data-advance-search="S">
      Show Advance Search 
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/simpanoz/u497ntcL/).

Can some one guide me how can I change icon to (glyphicon-chevron-up).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)** and **[`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)** , also I've updated your markup for making it simple

```js
jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').on('click', function() {
  var dh = jQuery(this).data('advance-search');
  if (dh === 'S') {
    jQuery(this).find('.text').text('Hide Advance Search')
      .end().data('advance-search', 'H')
      .find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
  } else if (dh === 'H') {
    jQuery(this).find('.text').text('Show Advance Search')
      .end().data('advance-search', 'S')
      .find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <a id="IdAdvanceSearch" href="javascript:;" class="col-sm-offset-2" data-advance-search="S">
    <span class="text">Show Advance Search </span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

or using your same markup you can do something like this

```js
jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').on('click', function() {
  var dh = jQuery(this).data('advance-search');

  if (dh === 'S') {
    jQuery(this).contents().eq(0).replaceWith('Hide Advance Search')
      .end().end().data('advance-search', 'H')
      .find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
  } else if (dh === 'H') {
    jQuery(this).contents().eq(0).replaceWith('Show Advance Search')
      .end().end().data('advance-search', 'S')
      .find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <a id="IdAdvanceSearch" href="javascript:;" class="col-sm-offset-2" data-advance-search="S">
    Show Advance Search
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

---

or just update the entire html content inside

```js
jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').on('click', function() {
  var dh = jQuery(this).data('advance-search');

  if (dh === 'S') {
    jQuery(this).data('advance-search', 'H')
      .html('Hide Advance Search<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>');
  } else if (dh === 'H') {
    jQuery(this).data('advance-search', 'S')
      .html('Show Advance Search<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <a id="IdAdvanceSearch" href="javascript:;" class="col-sm-offset-2" data-advance-search="S">
    Show Advance Search
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change your HTML like this-

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <a id="IdAdvanceSearch" href="javascript:;" class="col-sm-offset-2" data-advance-search="S">
      Show Advance Search 

     </a>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
   </div>
```

and modify your JQuery as below-

```
jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').on('click', function(){
var dh = jQuery("#IdAdvanceSearch").data('advance-search');

if(dh == 'S'){
  $('#IdAdvanceSearch').next('.glyphicon-chevron-down').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
 jQuery("#IdAdvanceSearch").text('Hide Advance Search');
 jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').data('advance-search', 'H');
}
else if(dh == 'H'){
 $('#IdAdvanceSearch').next('.glyphicon-chevron-up').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
 jQuery("#IdAdvanceSearch").text('Show Advance Search');
 jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').data('advance-search', 'S');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
 $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
```

There is a problem in the hierarchy of html too. Hope you are expecting this.

Put your span outside the anchor tag.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/u497ntcL/5/)

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code change to this

```
jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').on('click', function(){
  var dh = jQuery("#IdAdvanceSearch").data('advance-search');

    if(dh === 'S'){
       jQuery("#IdAdvanceSearch").html('Hide Advance Search<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>');
       jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').data('advance-search', 'H');
    }
    else if(dh === 'H'){
       jQuery("#IdAdvanceSearch").html('Show Advance Search<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>');
       jQuery('#IdAdvanceSearch').data('advance-search', 'S');
    }
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amrana83/rxw7dvnj/)

> Use jQuery **`html`** instead of jQuery **`text`** to allow insertion of glyphicon
>   & when hide pass down icon & when show pass up icon